# Skipping NULL values in column assignment

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

There is a database table containing address information like

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| name1       | name2 | name3 | street        | zip     | city |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 'Some name' | NULL  | ''    | 'Some street' | '12345' | NULL |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

so some fields may be NULL or empty.

Now I'd like to select

```
SELECT
  name1,  /* 'Some name' */
  name2,  /* NULL */
  name3,  /* '' */
  street, /* 'Some street' */
  zip,    /* '12345' */
  city,   /* NULL */

  adr1,   /* Should contain 'Some name' */
  adr2,   /* Should contain 'Some street' */
  adr3,   /* Should contain '12345' */
  adr4,   /* NULL */
  adr5,   /* NULL */
  adr6    /* NULL */
FROM
 adr
```

where `adr1` to `6` represent letterhead rows, which should be fillen in order of `name1`, `name2`, `name3`, `street`, `zip`, `city` but should skip NULL or empty values while assinging them.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try WHERE...?

Comment: Show what you want for expected results. And where are the columns, `adr1...adr6` coming from?

Comment: Can you give some more details about the expectations - what do you expect as a result (you can give an example). 
If you don't want to return the null columns at all then this can be handled in the application code.

Comment: Do you have a primary key column in this table?

Comment: The columns `adr1` to `6` are "virtual". The question is how to assign them.

Comment: May be using a function with `AdrRow(name1, name2, ..., ad)` returning the request address row.

Comment: @Inceddy Nice idea, crooss apply  with table-valued function, which can make a trick for one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little messy, and relies you have an ID column, however, I think this is what you are after:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT S.YourID,
           S.name1,
           S.name2,
           S.name3,
           S.street,
           S.zip,
           S.city,
           NULLIF(V.Adr,'') AS Adr,
           Line,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YourID, CASE WHEN NULLIF(V.Adr,'') IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY Line) AS RN
    FROM (VALUES(1, 'Some name',CONVERT(varchar(10),NULL),'','Some street','12345',CONVERT(varchar(10),NULL))) S(YourID,name1,name2,name3,street,zip,city)
         CROSS APPLY(VALUES(name1,1),(name2,2),(name3,3),(street,3),(zip,4),(city,5)) V(Adr,Line))
SELECT C.YourID,
       MAX(C.name1) AS name1,
       MAX(C.name2) AS name2,
       MAX(C.name3) AS name3,
       MAX(C.street) AS street,
       MAX(C.zip) AS zip,
       MAX(C.city) AS city,
       MAX(CASE WHEN C.RN = 1 THEN C.Adr END) AS Adr1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN C.RN = 2 THEN C.Adr END) AS Adr2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN C.RN = 3 THEN C.Adr END) AS Adr3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN C.RN = 4 THEN C.Adr END) AS Adr4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN C.RN = 5 THEN C.Adr END) AS Adr5,
       MAX(CASE WHEN C.RN = 6 THEN C.Adr END) AS Adr6
FROM CTE C
WHERE C.Adr IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY C.YourID;
```

Comment: Yep, looks messy - Especially when the "real" select contains about 50 columns from 7 tabels :/

Comment: I can only base a solution the single example we have @Inceddy . If your sample data isn't representative of your real data, the answer won't be either.

Comment: The sample just describes the problem and left out any meta information. Your answer indeed solves the problem but it's not "pretty" ^^

Comment: @Inceddy If this suggestion works (as you said) then please mark it as the answer to close the question and to let others find a solution to similar problems.